# PHP Sessions getting wiped between between SSL/non-SSL pages, even in separate tabs

Tags: php, session, ssl

Scenario: I'm on my web site http://domain.com/, and see some content I need to moderate. I click an 'admin this page' link to open in a new tab which sends me to https://domain.com/myadmin/ and I re-authenticate, navigate to the appropriate moderation panel of my site, do my work, and typically leave that tab open.

Now back on the non-SSL version of the site, I click around to other pages, etc., see something else to moderate, and whether I go back to my old https: //domain.com/myadmin/ tab, or open another new https: //domain.com/myadmin/ tab, suddenly my old session is gone, and I have to re-authenticate.

Currently, our session data is stored in Memcache. Our SSL-enabled node is a single machine. Our non-SSL site is load balanced across more than a dozen nodes. All nodes share a common code base via NFS, so the code is identical on all nodes, secure or not.

After doing lots of lurking and reading, I wondered if it had something to do with php.ini's setting of session.cookie_secure ... but since we force everyone using the secured /myadmin/ panel to re-authenticate, it seems that the secured session is just disappearing.

I think the problem is local to the node which answers to the SSL requests. If we open a tab to https: //domain.com/myadmin/ and log in, and then remove the /myadmin/ path and just navigate around our entire site as https: //domain.com/ it seems our session never disappears. But as soon as we click a link in the browser that forces us to the non-secure version of the site, our secure session goes poof.

Comment: To clarify, we're not looking to share data between the secure and non-secure sessions. We could be logged into domain.com as one user, and then log into the /myadmin/ secured panel as a totally different user. But as soon as we do anything on the non-secure site, the secure session at /myadmin/ goes poof.

Comment: Followup: I log into the non-SSL site, and I see a cookie with a PHPSESSID value, let's say it's abc123. I open a new tab, go to https://domain.com/myadmin/ and log in, and a second cookie is created with the *same* PHPSESSID value. Doing anything else on the non-SSL site must clear the flag(s) we set to indicate we're logged into the admin panel... I can't find any other reason.

Comment: Yes, a duplicate session id would certainly overwrite things. Are you making your own session ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change one of the session key names
   (i.e. `PHPSESSID _SECURE` or
   `PHPSESSIDS` for your secure
   connection), so you don't overwrite
   the cookie in the user's browser.
2. Check your path setting on your
   cookies to make sure they cover the
   parts of your website you wish.
3. If you don't want the secure session ID
   to be visible to non-secure
   connection you can set the secure
   flag on the cookie so it only is
   transferred to the same domain.

Comment: Thanks Yzmir, #1 was exactly my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's happening.

1. When a user visits http site with no visible cookie, a non-secure PHPSESSID cookie gets set
2. When a user visits admin site, a secure PHPSESSID cookie is created
3. When a secure cookie exists with the same name as a non-secure cookie that is being set, the secure cookie is replaced with the non-secure cookie

The solution, as Yzmir said, is to change the session key names to be distinct